# LastPass shows prompt to save password after clicking back

Tags: html, accessibility, custom-data-attribute, lastpass

I have a single page React app with a simple login form with two buttons `LOGIN` and `BACK`. If I click `BACK` LastPass still offers to save the entered username/password, even though I didn't login.

Is there any way to tell LastPass that the back button is a cancel button for the login form and that it shouldn't try to save the username/password in that case?

HTML looks something like this:

```
<input name="username" type="text" />
<button type="submit">LOGIN</button>
<button>BACK</button>
```

Comment: `<input type="button" value="Back" />` maybe ?

Comment: Have you tried `<button type="reset">` ?

Comment: @QuentinC No, I didn't. That sounds like it should work, I will try that.

Comment: @QuentinC That seems to work, if you add it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<input type="reset" />` or `<button type="reset">`.

As its name says, a reset button is ment to cancel a form. When it is activated, all user inputs are cancelled and the fields are reset back to their default values, i.e. the ones that were specified in the HTML code.

In JavaScript, You may intercept an activation of the reset button by using the reset event on the parent form, i.e. `form.onreset=...`, `form.addEvementListener('reset', ...)`  or `<form onreset="...">`.
Note that, as for submit buttons, it's a bad practice to intercept the click event directly on the button by using onclick: although there is no universal standard way to cancel the form as there is with the enter key to submit it (escape key don't cancel the form by default), you can't be sure that there is no other way to cancel the form than click on the reset button.